# DRY code to implement action listener (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, reduce

I'm now implementing a tray game, in which i use some JButton to represent the tray. But the tray makes 7x7, so to implement the action listener it's not so fun. I have a code like this now :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if (ae.getSource() == Bouton11)
            {
                this.PosePion(1, 1, Bouton11);
            }
            else if (ae.getSource() == Bouton21)
            {
                this.PosePion(2, 1, Bouton21);
            }
            else if (ae.getSource() == Bouton31)
            {
                this.PosePion(3, 1, Bouton31);
            }
            ......
    }
```

How can i reduce this sort of code please ? :/

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make your own listener type.** Your type should implement `ActionListener` (and thus the `actionPerformed` method), and be constructed with three parameters: the button and the two integers. The reason why you need these three parameters is so that you can pass them to the `PosePion` method (which should be capitalized `posePion`, by the way).

For example:

```
class PoseActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JButton button;
    private int a, b;

    public PoseActionListener(JButton btn, int a, int b) {
        this.button = btn;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        posePion(a, b, btn);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
button11.addActionListener(new PoseActionListener(button11, 1, 1);
button12.addActionListener(new PoseActionListener(button12, 1, 2);
```

Or, even better, create all buttons at once:

```
for (int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<=7; j++) {
        JButton btn = new JButton("Button " + i + ", " + j);
        // store the button in an array if you want
        btn.addActionListener(new PoseActionListener(btn, i, j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Place your JButtons in a 2D, 7x7 array when they are created.

Then in the listener method, loop through the array to determine which `JButton` was clicked.  Your looping indexes will help you determine what to pass to `PosePion`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, an know how i can place them into an array, but how do you determine which JButton was clicked with a loop, and how to pass it to PosePion for example ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you learn the Sun Java coding conventions.  Your code is hard to read.

I would consider having an individual ActionListener for each instance rather than one for all.

I'd also recommend a data structure and Command implementation to cut down on the mindless repetition.

Comment: We don't learn how to do this in class, just know how to implement one action listener... That's why i have some problems to implement this

Comment: You *need* to learn in class and use *your* brain, and not to do plain copypasting.